# How to get the clipboard icon

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I'd like to add the following feature in my Windows Phone 7.1 application :

- the user should be able to copy some text (in this case from a TextBlock) to the clipboard by "clicking" a Button.

What I'd like to do, in order to make the application integrated into the Windows Phone design, is to set the clipboard image to the mentioned button.

Setting an image into the content of the button is not an issue, nor is setting some text into the clipboard; there are a lot a documents about that.

Microsoft gives us some icons in the SDKs but I wasn't able to locate the clipboard icon file. Does any of you knows where I can find it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a very complete set of icons (including the "clipboard copy" one you were looking for) here: [Modern UI Icons](http://modernuiicons.com).

Answer (score 0):

I actually created one for one of my apps, your welcome to have it, use it how you wish.  I've put it on this link

[appbar.duplicate.rest.png](http://noteboxpro.co.uk/images/appbar.duplicate.rest.png)

Its white so select the entire page and you will see it and be able to right click save as PNG.

Comment: Thank you but this is not the exact icon I was looking for. I'm looking for the icon that's popup when you select some text for example in one of your email. It looks more like two files.